# How to detect that Delpi code is running in a DLL?

Tags: windows, delphi, dll

I am creating a [Windows] DLL which is primarily for use by non-delphi callers. I want to use some existing "library" code but there are some parts that might be inappropriate or problematic if they are being executed within a DLL.

Is there a way of detecting that the code is running within a DLL?

Comment: System.IsLibrary

Comment: Code is code. Shouldn't really matter whether it exists in a DLL or not. I suspect that what you really want to detect relates to the host rather than your code.

Comment: @David You are right in that I want to know "what environment am I in?". This still may be a useful part of the puzzle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`System.IsLibrary`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IsLibrary)

> Indicates whether the module is a shared library.
>
> The IsLibrary variable is True if the module is a dynamic link library (DLL).

Comment: Wow. Thank you - just running out the clock now so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if MainInstance <> HInstance then // => DLL
```

**IsLibrary always has the value FALSE** if runtime packages **rtl** are used consistently. The IsLibrary *and IsConsole* variables are global in this case. The values ​​are set by the exe. They are not changed by the DLL.